# running docker commands on host

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I have my docker-machine running, and from my HOST (Macbook) I can run things like `docker-machine ssh` or `docker-machine ls` and see the expected results.

However, from my host machine, I can NOT run "docker engine" commands, such as `docker ps`, etc. In order to run those commands I need to ssh into my docker-machine and run them there, does that sound correct, or do I have something setup incorrectly?

It seems like it *might* be ok, but then again some of the tutorials I am reading have led me to believe that running docker commands on the host (as long as they are run within the /Users directory would automatically be run on the docker-machine vm. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run `docker` commands on your host, you need to set the necessary environment variables to tell your host Docker client where the Docker daemon is located (which is inside the Docker Machine).  These environment variables are output by [`docker-machine env NAME_OF_MACHINE`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/), and then you just need to `eval` them: `eval "$(docker-machine env NAME_OF_MACHINE)"`

Comment: Thanks! Is that the most common/recommended approach to running your docker commands, or is it considered just as well to ssh into the docker-machine to run your docker specific operations?

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald: It's the recommended approach; [see step 5 of the official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine).

Comment: Thank you for the link! Being new to docker, keeping the docs related to the host machine, docker-machine, images, and containers straight has been a bit of a challenge. Cheers